# How to split a CLOB content based on a delimiter?

Tags: sql, database, blob

I have a CLOB content like below,

```
Thu Jun 24 12:04:58 PDT 2004|jnarayan|Scott from Sales
        called, missing payment, I will let Antonio know of this and ask
        him to reverse payment. However, still short of the total past
        due. I am UNLOCKING THE PORTS, BUT COSTOMER HAS TO SEND IN THE
        REMAINING PAST DUE BALANCES AT THE EARLIEST.
```

Based on the Delimiter '|' I want to split this content and I want to insert into a new table

```
'TEST'
-------
```

and columns like

```
note_date,
name,
note_text
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And your example data is a `CLOB` (**character** large object) not a `BLOB` (which is a **binary** large object).

Comment: sorry you are right that is clob only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the above text is in the column 'comments' and the type is CLOB

```
select SUBSTR(COMMENTS, 1,INSTR(COMMENTS, '|',1,1)-1) dates,
       SUBSTR(COMMENTS, INSTR(COMMENTS, '|',1,1)+1,(INSTR(COMMENTS, '|',1,2)-INSTR(COMMENTS, '|',1,1)-1) ) EMPLOYEE_NAME,
       SUBSTR(COMMENTS, INSTR(COMMENTS, '|',1,2)+1,length(COMMENTS) ) COMMENTS 
  from MIG_BRM_ACCT_NOTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Oracle you can create a function that use the **substr** function (included in PLQSL) for split the clob.

Comment: Or use the Oracle built in support for RegEx which is likely to be more efficient with CLOB data ([REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm))

Comment: yes i want to use plsql only can you please give me code for that